# Sending message to serviceActivator in Spring Integration after sending response in TCP gateway

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

My Spring Integration application built on TCP gateway is working well. It takes request message coming to TCP gateway and forwards the message to serviceActivator for preparing the response and the response is sent to the client.

I would like to save the message to database after sending to the client. I am just wondering whether I can forward the message to another serviceActivator after sending the response to the client.

If yes, how should spring configuration be setup? 
I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Here is the spring context file:

```
<beans>
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
            type="server"
            port="${availableServerSocket}"
            single-use="true"
            so-timeout="10000"
            using-nio="false" 
            serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
            deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
            />

        <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer"/>

        <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
            connection-factory="crLfServer"
            request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
            error-channel="errorChannel"
            reply-timeout="10000"/> <!-- reply-timeout works on inbound-gateway -->

        <int:channel id="toSA" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
            ref="myService"
            method="prepare"/>

        <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
            input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
            output-channel="toSA"/>

        <int:transformer id="errorHandler"
            input-channel="errorChannel"
            expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"/>
</beans>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `<publish-subscribe-channel>` as an `output-channel` for that `<service-activator>`. One of the subscribers would be `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` to store reply to the DB. Another subscriber should be `<bridge>` without an `output-channel` assuming reply to the `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway`>.

But yeah, it is **before** sending to client...

For that purpose you can extend `Serializer` and perform desired logic with the `byte[]` already after performing `super.serialize()`.

Comment: You can put `order="1"` on the bridge (together with an `output-channel` which is the `reply-channel` on the inbound gateway) and `order="2"` on the jdbc adapter and the reply will be sent first.